# Row State of child table gets modified after updating parent table

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset, tableadapter

I have dataset with two tables: `Computers` and `Hardware`.
`Hardware` table has foreign key relation constraint to `Computers` ID. 
The problem is I cannot update `Hardware` table in the database with table adapter. 
After calling `computersTableAdapter.Update(DataSet.Computers)` the row states of `Hardware` changes from `Added` to `Unchanged`

This even happens when i set `computersTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i did not set `Nested` property  `True` on foreign key relation.